# Sqlparameter.Dbtype.Xml giving error in .net compact framework

Tags: c#, sql, .net-cf-3.5

Im working on an app for windows CE and trying to access a stored procedure in SQL server.

I need to pass XML parameter but its giving me the following runtime exception :

```
Invalid SqlDbType enumeration value: 25
```

at this line :

```
SqlParameter XMLDoc = new SqlParameter("@XMLDoc", SqlDbType.Xml);
```

Same code works in normal .net framework so I guess its something specific to compact framework.

msdn says its supported for compact framework.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

*I had similar experience and this is how I managed it.*

**Use `SqlDbType.NVarChar` instead of `SqlDbType.Xml` as shown below**

```
DataSet dsWithSomeTable=new DataSet("NameSpace");
tblTable.TableName="Table";
dsWithSomeTable.Tables.Add(tblTable);

  SqlParameter xml = new SqlParameter
            {
                ParameterName = "@XML",
                SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar,
                Value = dsWithSomeTable.GetXml()
            };
```

**And on the other end in stored procedure handle it by converting it to XML type**

```
-- =============================================
-- Description: Inserts records from CE device
-- =============================================
CREATE PROCEDURE [Inventory].[uspCEInserXML] 
    @XML NVARCHAR(MAX) = NULL
AS
BEGIN
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED
--Receives parameter as NVarchar since the CE environment doesnt support XML type param
--and converting into XML
DECLARE @CXML XML=CAST(@XML AS XML)
 SELECT              
      XTab.value('Col1[1]','int') AS[Col1],                   
      XTab.value('Col2[1]','int') AS[Col2],              
      XTab.value('Col3[1]','float') AS[Col3]
 INTO #TMP
 FROM @CXML.nodes('NameSpace/Table') XTab([XTab])              
END
GO
```